# .show(): how to call .show() on a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, show

I fixed my code but I'm having glitchy behavior. Specifically, when the mouse is no longer on the 'td.component' the buttons should be hidden but upon moving the mouse really fast over the various 'td.component's, some of these elements still show the buttons. Any thoughts on how I could fix this?

Thanks.

Code below:

```
$(function() {

var $newButton = $('<button class = "new"><img class = icon src = "images/new.png" >new</img></button>');
var $deleteButton = $('<button class = "delete"><img class = icon src = "images/delete.png" >delete</img></button>');
var $saveButton = $('<button id = "save">Save</button>');

for (i = 42; i > 0; i--) {
    $table.append('<tr><td class = "number">' + i + 
        '</td><td class = "component"></td></tr>');

}

//appends to all 'td.component'
$('td.component').append($newButton).append($deleteButton);
//hides all buttons
$('button.new').hide();
$('button.delete').hide();


$('td.component').mouseover(function(e) {
    $(this).find('button.new').show();
    $(this).find('button.delete').show();
});


$('td.component').mouseout(function(e) {
    $(this).find('button.new').hide();
    $(this).find('button.delete').hide();
});

$('button.new').mouseout(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$('button.delete').mouseout(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

});

Comment: Without knowing what your DOM structure looks like, there's no way of telling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('td.component').mouseover(function(e) {

    $(this).find('button.new').show();
    $(this).find('button.delete').show();

});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t5v3647/).

You'll probably want to hide the buttons once the mouse leaves.

As @elzi pointed out, if you just want to show/hide them on hover, you are best off using CSS [hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover):

```
td.component button {
    display: none;
}

td.component:hover button {
    display: inline;  
}
```

(classes ignored for simplicity)

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t5v3647/1/).

Comment: Assuming that the buttons are elements of the TD itself, this is it.

Comment: This answers the question, but unless the OP wants the buttons to permanently show after hover, they should probably use CSS instead of JS. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` to execute the set of functions on that element.

```
$('td.component').mouseover(function(e) {
   $(this).find('button.new').show();
   $(this).find('button.delete').show();
});
```

This would find the buttons inside that particular element.